# Acumatica customization with Stopwatch

Tags: customization, acumatica

I want to create stopwatch in CRCase screen as below picture:

[image]

I add new buttons as: Start, Pause, Stop and Label of running time. But I have no idea about how to create stopwatch event handle?

Comment: I think you better off create 2 new fields for a Start Time and End Time for your DAC. Under a button just set the start time for one button and end for another (or re-use a button to change the label after started.) Then calculate another field to show total time if you need to.

Comment: Why do I need to create 2 new fields for start and end time?

Comment: Because the user might "start" and leave the page or even logout (could happen from session timeout). This way the start is recorded in the database and the user can return at any time and "stop" which then records the end time. From the end time you can get your total time when the end time is entered. This is just a suggestion - but a problem I would see based on your question and the page is refreshed.

Comment: For my question, it's just simple. User clicks on Start so the Stopwatch will start running and when user "Pause" the Stopwatch also pauses and "Stop" the Stopwatch will stop too. It will happen only user login not leave the page or logout. I need the box for storing the number when it pauses and continues.

Comment: Assuming these are short time periods and you do not need to save the data (for display only), I would look into some type of javascript stopwatch to have the values constantly update. Otherwise I am not sure how you will be able to have the page constantly display the time without a contant page refresh. Try to google JavaScript stopwatch library to see if this helps

Comment: Would you give me a document about Acumatica with Javascript? If Acumatica has any course resource, I would like to read.

Comment: I have not needed to use any Javascript with Acumatica so I cannot help there. You could try searching the Acumatica pages for "type="text/javascript"" or something similar.

Comment: Anyways, thank for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find sample [here](https://github.com/Acumatica/Case-Stopwatch-sample). Check it out and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: hi there, I've written this code `window.onload = function(){
 var ele = px_all["ctl00_phF_tab_t0_edStatus"].getValue();
 if(ele == "CL" || ele == "CD"){
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonStart").setAttribute("disabled", "true");  
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonStart").classList.remove("ButtonH"); 
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonStart").classList.add("ButtonD"); 
 }
 alert (ele);
};` to disable the buttons when the task completed or Cancel but it seems get error **Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined
    at window.onload**